# no option to clone in visual studio from azure devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, clone

I want to clone the existing project from Azure DevOps in Visual Studio but there is no option to do such a thing. How can I fix it? (in youtube videos there is an option)
[image]

Comment: Is that just a “most popular list”? Given this situation, I’d probably open git-bash and use `git clone` from the appropriate remote repository.

Comment: Can you view the repository online? If it is (or isn’t) there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be available, otherwise can you try to log out and log in again?

One other way to try is using the git-bash and use regular **`git clone`** method

Follow the instructions given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/clone?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio)